# How to assign values to array using groovy?

Tags: groovy

***Response:***

```
[
    {"msisdn":"85237009372","name":"Vicky","carrier":"AIRTEL"},
    {"msisdn":"85237009373","name":"Vicky1","carrier":"AIRTEL"}
]
```

I want to extract the all name from response and assign it to array/list?

***Code:***

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// Retrieve valid mptu Amounts from GET mptu-amounts response
context.responseContent = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("xxxx").getPropertyValue("r_responseContent")

try
{
  responseContentParsed = new JsonSlurper().parseText( context.responseContent )

  context.mptuValidAlias = responseContentParsed.name[0]
  log.info(context.mptuValidAlias)
}
```

It is retrieving the first row, name (i.e) vicky only.. i wanted to extract name of all rows and assign it to list.. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
context.mptuValidAlias = responseContentParsed.name[0]
```

to this:

```
context.mptuValidAlias = responseContentParsed.name
```